# How to save the best model during training?

Tags: python, object-detection, tflite

From tflite_model_maker we can do

```
from tflite_model_maker import object_detector
model = object_detector.create()
```

The create function will train and create a model.
During the training step, is there a way to save the best model or even create an early stop event? In the comments in the Google Colab notebook, I see that we can keep one eye on the validation loss and interrupt the training when we see the value increasing. I would like to have an automatic solution.